# User_id issue after session is set

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to retrieve data from the database but user_id is issue...Session is already set but not work ...

```
function user_data($user_id){
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if($func_get_args > 1){
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields =' ` ' . implode('` , `',$func_get_args) . '`';
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`= $user_id ") or die(mysql_error());
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query);
        print_r($data);
        die();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Where i need to change?

Comment: There is no reference to a php session here.

Comment: My answer obviously wasn't clear enough:  All you need to do is remove the _spaces_ between the single quotes on the implode line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the lack of context in your question it is difficult to answer.

The code you have submitted builds an SQL statement which is dependent on how you call that function.

If you were to call the function with these arguments:

```
user_data(5, 'name', 'age');
```

It would result in the following SQL query:

```
SELECT ` name` , `age` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`= 5
```

Notice the space before name?  That creates an invalid column name.

```
 $fields =' ` ' . implode('` , `',$func_get_args) . '`';
             ^ Problem space here
```

The SQL would also be invalid if you called it with just one argument.

```
user_data(5);
```

Results in:

```
SELECT FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`= 5
```

Which I assume should read:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`= 5
```

I've changed the `func_get_args > 1` line and removed spaces on your `implode` line.

```
function user_data($user_id) {
    $data = array();
    $user_id = (int) $user_id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if($func_num_args > 1){
        unset($func_get_args[0]);
        $fields ='`' . implode('`,`',$func_get_args) . '`';
    } else {
        $fields = ' * ';
    }
    $sql = "SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`= $user_id ";
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: $field data is $user_data = user_data($session_user_id,'user_id','username','password','first_name','last_name','email');

Comment: Okay, it's the space in the implode line that is causing your error.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
function user_data($user_id,$fields=array('*')){
    $data = array();
    $fields = implode(', ',$fields);
    $query1 = "SELECT {$fields} FROM users WHERE user_id= {$user_id}";
    $query = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query);
    return $data;        
}
user_data(5);
user_data(5,array('username','email'));
```

Query :

```
1.) SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id= 5
2.) SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE user_id= 5
```

Comment: You have just changed the interface to the function with no apparent gain.

Comment: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: @progrock : I just use the different way to do this. it does not mean my answer is wrong.

Comment: Sorry how have you answered this?

Comment: in your case and in my case result will be same if we take same fields name.

Comment: when i add star then its show array result but why $fields is not working

Comment: Here : same fields means like : name, age, phone. not *. Even i know it will not run give you database error. Error in query.

Comment: ok i am going to show you my $field query    if (logged_in() === true){
 $session_user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
 $user_data = user_data($session_user_id,'user_id','username','password','first_name','last_name','email');
 }
$errors

Comment: In my case it will be like this : $user_data = user_data($session_user_id,array('user_id','username','password','first_name','last_na‌​me','email')); Even i dont have time for this silly discussion. Please go ahead.

Comment: @user3809295 : i did not expect atleast negative voting for this answer. it is little bit different (using array) but not wrong.